# QWidget stays within parent QWidget

Tags: qt, qwidget

i'm quite new to Qt and i've a question.

I've got an application with multiple windows/QFrame. I'd like them to only exist within the mainwindow (it's also the parent gadget). When I move them, I want the to stay within the parent gadget.

1. Is is possible ?
2. If yes, how ? 
   I've been through the Qt doc and i've found nothing. I though maybe a simple option can do that. Or do I have to create a new Widget with customs mouse Event methods ?

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a [Multiple Document Interface (MDI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_document_interface) GUI you can use the [`QMdiArea`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qmdiarea.html) and [`QMdiSubWindow`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qmdisubwindow.html) classes to implement this. Have a look at the detailed description section of `QMdiArea` for using it with a QMainWindow example, but it also works on any other widget as well.